# Swing: JComboBox + JList + Symbol after each selection

Tags: java, swing

I have a ComboBox with 3 items (salad, carrot, onion) after each selection
I should to see the element in my list.

Example, I select carrot then onion after carrot and then salad ; I should have in my JList:

```
Carrot
Onion
Carrot
Salad
```

(I don't have problem concerning this step)

Now, I would like to add a symbol ("*") after each add of element chosen for example.

```
Carrot **
Onion  *
Salad  *
```

How do I display a symbol "*"  after each element ?
Do you have an idea ?

Here is my code for now.

```
private void jComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                           
        // 

        if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            model.addElement(evt.getItem().toString());
        list.setModel(model);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea here use object which allows to count selection number. Here is a small example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TestCombo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test");
        Item[] items = {null, new Item("Carrot"), new Item("Onion"), new Item("Salad")};
        final JComboBox<Item> combo = new JComboBox<>(items);
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Item item = (Item) combo.getSelectedItem();
                if (item != null) {
                    item.incrementStars();
                }
            }
        });
        frm.add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.setSize(500, 150);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class Item {
        private String text;

        private int starNumber;

        public Item(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public void incrementStars() {
            starNumber++;
        }

        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(text);
            // add the required number of stars.
            if (starNumber > 0) {
                result.append(' ');
                for (int i = 0; i < starNumber; i++) {
                    result.append('*');
                }
            }
            return result.toString();
        }
    }
}
```